# Query SQL based on month

Tags: php, mysql

So in my page i have [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs_open) tab bar, where each tab has a month name for the current year: January, February, March and so on...

For each tab I want to query from SQL where **datetime** column is equal to that month. I have done some research and testing, and found out that by using this code below, I am able to get result from the current month:

```
foreach($link->query('
SELECT name 
     , COUNT(*) 
  FROM sales 
 WHERE sale = "OK" 
   AND date > date_sub(now(), interval 1 month) 
 GROUP 
    BY name 
 order 
    by COUNT(*) DESC
 ') as $row) {
```

This is an example on how the date is stored: `2020-09-02 11:42:58`.

But now I am stuck. How can I create a query to get result for only January, only February, only March and so on... ?

EDIT:

This is the tabs:

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År')">Januar</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År')">Februar</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År')">Mars</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År')">April</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År')">Mai</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År')">Juni</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År')">Juli</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År')">August</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År')">September</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År')">Oktober</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År')">November</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År')">Desember</button>
```

Comment: `WHERE MONTH(date) = 1` for January.

Comment: @Barmar And if I want the current year also, will that be like `WHERE MONTH(date) = 1 AND YEAR = CURDATE()`?

Comment: `AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE())`

Comment: @Barmar Ah, thanks!

Comment: @Barmar Do I have to create 12 different queries, or can I do this with only one?

Comment: you can provide the month number as a parameter that you get from the form.

Comment: @Barmar Do I assign it to a button? Please check my edit on my question,

Comment: `openCity(event, 'Ar', 1)` for January, `openCity(event, 'Ar', 2)` for February, and so on. Then you send the third parameter in the AJAX request to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Add the month number to your `openCity()` function.

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År', 1)">Januar</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'År', 2)">Februar</button>
...
```

Send the third argument as a parameter to PHP in the AJAX request. Then use that in the query.

```
$sql = "SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS sales_count
        FROM sales
        WHERE sale = 'OK'
        AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW())
        AND MONTH(date) = ?");
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST['month']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nice, but how do I add that in the events? Because I guess I will need 12 different even classes? https://pastebin.com/i2Mhpwua (The `<div id="London" class="tabcontent">` in the example). Or do I add that one time inside the `foreach`?

Comment: I thought you were using the buttons you show in the question.

Comment: how is that pastebin relevant? There are no months there.

Comment: I am using the buttons, but the pastebin is from the example I am using.

Comment: My answer is based on the buttons you showed in the question, which are for months, not cities.

Comment: Maybe my English is bad, but yea, that is what I mean. But how do I add the `<table>"` code for each month? Inside the `foreach`?

Comment: Yes, just like how you generate a table from any other query.

Comment: I'm not going to tutor you on all the steps of generating HTML from SQL queries. There are many web sites that teach the basics.